# Adding signatures to emails via transport rule in exchange management console

Tags: email, exchange-2010, rules

I am trying to setup a transport rule in exchange management console which creates a signature at the end of a users emails.

This seems to work.  The problem however, is that the signature gets added to the end of the full chain of emails.  So if the email chain has say 10 emails going back for forward, instead of the signature getting added to each emails body text, it gets added to the very end of the email chain.

Is it possible to fix this, so the signature doesn't get added to the very end of the whole email chain, but instead gets added to the bottom of the new emails body?

Using exchange server 2010

Answer (score 0):

When establishing an Exchange transportation rules, it append the text to the end of the entire mail item as it passes through the transport server. It doesn't have ability to insert the signature under new replies or forwarded emails.

Depending on the sizes of your organization, you might want to implement signature via Outlook clients if it can be easily implemented or deployed via scripting. Otherwise, you might need to look into third-party tool with a more comprehensive features.

Additionally, if you want to avoid appending multiple signature to a large email chain, you probably should consider exception rules to exclude subjects with "FW:" or "RE:", etc